# Can't find the problem in code to dynamically assign a component name based on user input in React

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to render a react component depending on user input. I have researched and found a solution I could understand, but I've been unsuccessful. I will share the parts of the code I think are relevant to identify the problem.

This is how I am importing the components I want to render conditionally to user input:

```
import { ComponentOne, ComponentTwo }  from './component-list/components'
```

This is how the components are being exported:

```js
export function ComponentOne() {

  return (
    <>
      <div>This is ComponentOne</div>
    </>
  );
};

export function ComponentTwo() {

  return (
    <>
      <div>This is ComponentTwo</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

As per the research I made, I made an array of my two imports, so that I can access them using a string:

```js
const Components= [];
Components['ComponentOne'] = ComponentOne;
Components['ComponentTwo'] = ComponentTwo;
```

Then I do the following test:

```
let ComponentName = Components['ComponentOne'];
return <ComponentName />
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: do `const Components= {};`

Comment: You cannot set values in an array like that, that is meant for objects. Also why are you trying to store a component in an array/object? Can't you just import it where you need it?

Comment: @YashJoshi Thanks for the suggestion! but I am getting the same error :/

Comment: Can you add full code on how you are using it ? Try using codesandbox.io to share reproducible issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot index an array by strings. Moreover, when you want to render JSX as a tag directly, it needs to be a class or function as mentioned in the error message. In your usecase, if you want to render the appropriate content, the following code snippet may work:

```
//use object to index by string
const components = {
  component1: <ComponentOne />,
  component2: <ComponentTwo />
}

render() {
  return (
     <>{components["component1"]}</>
    )
}
```

Comment: It worked!! The next problem I'm having is to dynamically assign the "componentX" part inside the brackets, because my intention is to have dynamic assignment of the component name. Would you mind helping me out with that?